Custom ChatGPT action retrieving latest stock price from Alpha Vantage API via OpenAI Schema
I am trying to create an action in a custom GPT that uses the Alpha Vantage API to access the latest stock price for a stock ticker the user provides.
It seems there is already a custom GPT doing exactly that, so it is certainly possible:
https://chatgpt.com/g/g-1Cm5lD4JV-stock-price-data-visualization-gpt
According to https://chatgpt.com/g/g-7a2H3kMFI-alphavantagegpt I should call GLOBAL_QUOTE to retrieve the latest stock price for a ticker. Therefore, I requested https://chatgpt.com/g/g-TYEliDU6A-actionsgpt to build an openAI schema:
Please read the documentation at https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/ and create an OpenAI schema 3.1.0 for the GLOBAL_QUOTE API call, specifically extracting the "05. price" data point for a specific stock ticker (i.e. the latest stock price).

The output for this prompt was:
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: Alpha Vantage API
  description: API for retrieving the latest stock price using the GLOBAL_QUOTE endpoint from Alpha Vantage.
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: https://www.alphavantage.co/query
    description: Alpha Vantage API server
paths:
  /:
    get:
      operationId: getLatestStockPrice
      summary: Get the latest stock price for a given ticker symbol
      parameters:
        - name: function
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          example: GLOBAL_QUOTE
          description: The API function to call. Should be set to GLOBAL_QUOTE.
        - name: symbol
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          description: The stock ticker symbol.
        - name: apikey
          in: query
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          description: Your API key for Alpha Vantage.
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response with the latest stock price
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  price:
                    type: string
                    description: The latest stock price (from "05. price").
              examples:
                example1:
                  summary: Example response
                  value:
                    price: "150.00"

I then created an API key at Alpha Vantage:
https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key
Using this key I tested retrieving stock data with curl (instead of "demo" I used my actual API key):
curl "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=AMZN&apikey=demo"

The response to the curl was:
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "AMZN",
        "02. open": "172.7800",
        "03. high": "178.9000",
        "04. low": "172.6000",
        "05. price": "178.5000",
        "06. volume": "43429355",
        "07. latest trading day": "2024-08-30",
        "08. previous close": "172.1200",
        "09. change": "6.3800",
        "10. change percent": "3.7067%"
    }
}

This seemed to work. I then added my API key into the customGPT action at the section "authentication" with "authentication type" of "API key" and "Auth Type" of "basic".
As an instruction to the customGPT I added the following text (again, instead of "demo" I used the actual API key):
When a user asks for the latest stock price of a stock ticker, please use the alphavantage action to obtain the stock price using the API key "demo".

Now when for example in the customGPT I ask "Please provide the latest stock prize of AMZN" then I get the following response:
[debug] Response received
{}
Error talking to

It seems that there was an issue retrieving the latest stock price for Amazon (AMZN) from the external service.

I interacted with chatGPT to get the call to work, but no luck. For example, I followed the instructions to install postman. The call with postman works, but not with the customGPT.
How can I get the customGPT to successfully retrieve the latest stock price for a stock ticker such as AMZN?
Thank you for your help!
